# The advantages and disadvantages of the program LaTeX

Tags: learning

I'm new, I need to study and write a term project in the program LaTeX. Asking for help in learning this program. Start studying the instructions of the teacher, study of the advantages and disadvantages of the program LaTeX. What are the advantages and disadvantages of the program LaTeX?

Comment: This place is for questions and answers, not for discussions.  I’m voting to close as opinion-based.

Comment: If you are seeking to learn LaTeX, see this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/10995